# Influx definition? (imputation)

Tags: multiple-imputation, mice

I'm confused by the notation in [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/missing-data-pattern.html#sec:mdpattern).

It seems to be saying that the influx is a function of the variable indexed by `j` (column number), as indicated by the LHS of the equation below.

On the RHS though, `j` is used as the index in a summation? I would think that to compute `I_j`, you would fix `j` and then this summation doesn't make sense? Or `j` is supposed be the lower bound (that seems wrong)?

[image]